# SPARK-SCALA: Update End date for a ID with the new start_date for the updated respective ID

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column `end_date` for an `id` with the value of `start_date` column of the updated record for the same `id` using Spark Scala

Consider the following Data frame:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|Value|start_date|
+---+---- +----------+
| 1 |   a | 1/1/2018 |
| 2 |   b | 1/1/2018 |
| 3 |   c | 1/1/2018 |
| 4 |   d | 1/1/2018 |
| 1 |   e | 10/1/2018|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Here initially start date of `id=1` is `1/1/2018`  and `value` is `a`, while on `10/1/2018(start_date)` the `value` of `id=1` became `e`. so i have to populate a new column `end_date` and populate value for  `id=1`  in the beginning to `10/1/2018` and `NULL` values for all other records for `end_date` column

Result should be like below:

```
+---+-----+----------+---------+
| id|Value|start_date|end_date |
+---+---- +----------+---------+
| 1 |   a | 1/1/2018 |10/1/2018|
| 2 |   b | 1/1/2018 |NULL     |
| 3 |   c | 1/1/2018 |NULL     |
| 4 |   d | 1/1/2018 |NULL     |
| 1 |   e | 10/1/2018|NULL     |
+---+-----+----------+---------+
```

I am using spark 2.3.

Can anyone help me out here please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Window function "lead":

```
val df = List(
  (1, "a", "1/1/2018"),
  (2, "b", "1/1/2018"),
  (3, "c", "1/1/2018"),
  (4, "d", "1/1/2018"),
  (1, "e", "10/1/2018")
).toDF("id", "Value", "start_date")

val idWindow = Window.partitionBy($"id")
  .orderBy($"start_date")

val result = df.withColumn("end_date", lead($"start_date", 1).over(idWindow))
result.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----------+---------+
|id |Value|start_date|end_date |
+---+-----+----------+---------+
|3  |c    |1/1/2018  |null     |
|4  |d    |1/1/2018  |null     |
|1  |a    |1/1/2018  |10/1/2018|
|1  |e    |10/1/2018 |null     |
|2  |b    |1/1/2018  |null     |
+---+-----+----------+---------+
```